# Automate ''I Agree" after opening a weppage

Tags: iphone

I am writing an app to open a webpage but the page before asks for an agreement to use it. Can I write a script to outomate and save this response.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Probably not. And even if you could, are you sure your users *want* to agree to whatever you plan on automatically agreeing them to? Probably not to that too...

Comment: Not to mention that even if you could pull that off reliably, very likely nothing you'd force the users to agree to would have legal value...

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the specific implementation of the "I Agree" functionality.  If its just through a GET form submission, you can append whatever variable they chose to your URI.  If its a POST form submission, you can make a POST request from NSUrlConnection to pass the variable on.  If its just a simple "I Agree" command button, it might be as simple as figuring out what the destination page is.

Long story short, you'll have to examine how they're submitting the 'I Agree' and recreate that functionality in your app.

As to the moral/legal issues raised by Jason, he has a bit of a point.  The TOS is usually there to enact some form of agreement between the web site and its users.  By programmatically skipping this, you are causing your users to no longer be entered into this agreement - which may cause issues in the future with the web site and its owners.  Its certainly something to consider if this is going to be a widely used application and the TOS is more than a boilerplate.

You may consider implementing a 'more attractively' displayed version of their TOS in order to allow the user to understand what the web site wants them to agree to.